# How to block root user by sticky bit for removing a file

Tags: linux

> How to block root user for deleting a file by using sticky bit. I do not want to use 'chattr' command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't block root user from anything. root has all privileges.

Comment: Thank you Foch for replying but is there anyway to deny root user temporarily for deleting files by using sticky bit as like as "chattr +i" command can restrict modification of file temporarily.

Comment: using chattr +i will keep root (or anyone ) from changing/deleting  the file, but root can simply run chattr -i and then delete it. so its not a solution unless you are trying to stop an accidental deletion. in truth you can't keep root from doing anything since be design root has all privileges.